# MDX YTD function doesn't calculate correcty if the row is empty

Tags: ssas, mdx

My SQL server is 2008 R2. YTD function works fine except the following case.

For example if I have amount field and break down by the category (AAA, BBB, CCC). YTD doesn't show the BBB Value ($200) for Feb because it exist in Jan but not in Feb.

[Amount]
2011
 JAN
   AAA $100
   BBB $200
 FEB
   AAA $100
   CCC $300

[YTD Amount]
2011
 JAN
   AAA $100
   BBB $200
 FEB
   AAA $200
   CCC $300

This is my formula for the YTD calculated field.

AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Amount])

How can show the value of BBB for Feb ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a calculated measure to force a 0 when there is no value:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Amount Or Zero] as
Iif(ISEMPTY( [Measures].[Amount]),0, [Measures].[Amount])
```

And then:

```
AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Amount Or Zero])
```